# How to change the image of a CCSprite in cocos2d v3.x

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, ccsprite

In cocos2d 2.x we change the image of a CCSprite using CCTexture. But in cocos2d 3.x CCTextureCache seems to be deprecated as Xcode warns me : "**undeclared identifier 'CCTextureCache'**". Or may be am I miss something as I'm new to cocos.

So how can we change the image of a CCSprite in v3 ??

Thank you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think I know how to do.

1. We have to use a spriteSheet built with TexturePacker [note : may be it's wrong to speak about external resources like it on SO] for example (let's say we have 2 images : monster_01.png and monster_02.png).
2. We add the .plist and the .png into xCode
3. We put the spritesheet in cache
4. and then we can create a CCSprite with a frame using a item of the spritesheet.
5. This image can be changed.

Some code :

**3) We put in cache**

```
[[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache] addSpriteFramesWithFile:@"monsterSpriteSheet.plist"];
```

**4) We create the sprite**

```
CCSprite * mySprite = [CCSprite initWithSpriteFrame: [CCSpriteFrame frameWithImageNamed: @"monster_01.png"]];
```

**5) To change image :**

```
 [mySprite setSpriteFrame:[CCSpriteFrame frameWithImageNamed: @"monster_02.png"]];
```

This works perfectly with cocos2d v3.

I spent 6 hours to have this process. Sometimes I feel stupid.

Comment: Awesome.  Don't feel stupid.  90%+ of google searches for this question will gave me answers for cocos2d v2 or early, which are flat out wrong.  I was thrill to find your post.  One correction though.  I think it should be spriteWithSpriteFrame, not initWithSpriteFrame.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by using this

CCSpriteFrameCache and after that you can change you sprite by using function setSpriteFrame of ccsprite.

Comment: In the future please write out the code.  See @Pax's answer.